# How do I save the date within a cell as the filename?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to have the date from cell C2 saved in the file name. The issue I believe I'm having is the date value contains "/" which can't be saved in the filename and I don't know a work around.

I tried copying and pasting C2 to O2 and doing whatever I could to change the value from a date the format/text and keep the date but I wasn't having any luck.

```
Sub Bigtime()
'
' Bigtime Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+B

' String
    Dim path As String
        path = "C:\Users\CDoz\OneDrive\Documents\Bigtime Excel\"
' Turn off pop up alerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
' Delete Columns
    Columns("L:L").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
' Color Fill
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = x1Solid
        .PatternColorIndex = x1Automatic
        .Color = 5296274
    End With
' Date Format
    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("O2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yy;@"
    Range("O2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "4/29/2022"
' Strings
        
    Dim datefname As String
        datefname = Range("O2")
    Dim fname As String
        fname = datefname & " MLV Tasks"
' Save
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=path & fname, FileFormat:=51
        .Close
    End With
' Turn pop up alerts back on
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `.SaveAs Filename:=path & Format(Range("C2").value, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " MLV Tasks.xlsx", FileFormat:=51`

Comment: Note also you have `x1Solid` should be `xlSolid` same for `x1Automatic`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Format()` in VBA to format a date as a string useable in a filename:

```
.SaveAs Filename:=path & Format(Range("C2").value, "yyyy-mm-dd") &_
                   " MLV Tasks.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `Format` displays the date due to regional language settings, whereas `Application.Text` shows the en-us wording. @TimWilliams